# How to download files from Firebase Storage using WorkManager in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage, android-workmanager

I'm trying to download a zip file from Firebase Storage every 2 hours using `WorkManager`.
The following is the `dowork` function.

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    val storageRef = storage.reference
    val pathReference = storageRef.child("customerdata.zip")

    Log.v("SysLog", "File download starting...") // This log can be seen in Logcat

    val localFile = File.createTempFile("customerdata", ".zip")

    pathReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.v("SysLog", "File downloaded successfully")
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.v("SysLog", "File download failed with error: ${it.localizedMessage}")
    }

    return Result.success()
}
```

The `dowork` method is getting called without any problem. But the `addOnSuccessListener` is never called. And after about 10 minutes `addOnFailureListener` gets called with error message

> The operation retry limit has been exceeded

This problem only occurs only when the app is minimized and the phones screen is turned off. Otherwise the whole this works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure if this is the actual issue but the `.` dot is not need on `File.createTempFile` method. The rest looks fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getFile()` is asynchronous and always returns immediately.  The callback attached to the Task it returns are invoked some time later, after the download completes.  This means that your `doWork` function always returns `Result.success()` immediately, regardless of what happens with the download.  This is not what you want - your function should return a result only **after** the download finishes.

You will need to either:

1. Make this function block until the download finishes.
2. Use the asynchronous version of WorkManager workers to return a ListenableFuture that gets triggered when the work is complete.

Comment: I tried blocking the function and it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, I've seen answers suggesting `CountDownLatch` to block `doWork()` and `ListenableWorker` is called on the main thread so that we need to implement background by ourselves. What is the more appropriated way of waiting an answer from FirebaseStorage for an app that is going to be open to the public?